# How use a js library in my web flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm a junior flutter developer and i have a question
I'm creating a barcode scanner project
I tried every libraries in pub dev. They work in my abdroind phone but don't work in web and it's important for me to have a web version
I searched and finally i find that the only way is to add Javascript's libraries to my project
I think that I should use import_js_library & js library but I dont know how

Comment: take a look on my answeres, how to call js script in dart. i think this will help.

Comment: try my new plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/qr_bar_code_scanner_dialog/example

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [js](https://pub.dev/packages/js) package for this.

- Add js package to your project
- Create a .js file under web folder
- Write your js code in .js file.
- You can call a javascript method from your dart code.
- Refer this [article](https://medium.com/7span/flutter-web-javascript-everything-that-you-need-to-know-b07a32d7ad56) for more details
- You can also refer this [demo](https://github.com/pratikbutani/flutter_web_js/) on Github. It has base code for Flutter - JS Integration